# tensor extension of one-dimensional index into multi-dimensional index

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I wanna make a function of a multi-dimensional array from one-dimensional index array with any dimension.
For example, I have

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])
def extend_array(x,d)
```

If I put d=2, then the resulting array is

```
[[1,1],
 [1,2],
 [1,3],
 [2,1],
 [2,2],
 [2,3],
 [3,1],
 [3,2],
 [3,3]]
```

or input can be (n,d) instead of (x,d) so that n refers

```
np.array(range(1,n+1))
```

I think there is a function for this, but I cannot find one. 
Would you please help me with this problem?

Comment: I didn't find such a tag so added 'python' tag. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
t=list(product(x,repeat=d))
```

This will gives the desired result.